# How do I write a Dart web app that uses spawnUri and works with both Dartium and dart2js?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I want to write a concurrent web app (using either raw Workers or isolates as workers). The Dart API for isolates is `spawnUri`, which takes a URI that points to a script.

In Dartium, that script is a `.dart` file. In Chrome/Firefox/etc that script is a `.dart.js` file.

I need to detect what runtime I'm in so I can configure the URI for `spawnUri` correctly. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: For interested developers, here's a complete example: https://github.com/sethladd/dart_worker_isolates_dart2js_test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpawnUri automatically appends ".js" when compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: AWESOME!! Thanks, I should have expected that. :) I opened https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16211 to document it (unless I missed it?)

Answer (score 1):

How about using transformers? [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1juHkCRg-1YH6LvwhGPHgF2ihX-UQtR1fv-8aknO7t_4/edit) is a document about how transformers work, some Google internal documentation. There's also some info about transformers on pub pages - [assets and transformers](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/assets-and-transformers.html). What you could do is use transformers to output "rewrite" your files a bit to use correct url.